# How to findout the which line is breaking in load file function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trying to load the file data into database table. While inserting somewhere it is breaking,please anyone tell me how to find out which line it is breaking?

Here is my  function:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE gtac7_rns
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES STARTING BY 'GTAC-LOGS:' 
IGNORE 0 LINES     (EntryTS,UserName,CmdAuthorized,CmdType,Cmd,DeviceIP,DevicePort,SessionSource,DomainName,DomainId,ServerID,BindIP,ServerPort,Service,CmdArgs,PrivLvl,TaskId) set DeviceIP =       INET6_ATON(DeviceIP), SessionSource = INET6_ATON(SessionSource), BindIP = INET6_ATON(BindIP),Cmd = REPLACE(Cmd, '#', '|')
```

Comment: hows your sample file data look like?

Comment: ACDN|chcil00002cce9|1001|1|pfe-7/1/0|800000000||05/26/2014|00:00:00|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3600^M
ACDN|chlnc00001cce9|987|135|xe-7/2/0.101|10000000000||05/26/2014|00:00:00|69085854450|0|49327117|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3600^M
ACDN|chlnc00001cce9|990|135|xe-7/3/0.104|10000000000||05/26/2014|00:00:00|214221600|0|168882|3|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3600^M
ACDN|chlnc00001cce9|993|135|xe-7/3/0.101|10000000000||05/26/2014|00:00:00|80943673050|0|57540717|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3600^M

Comment: file contains above data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a big file you can try replace '\n' in notepad++

Comment: Please tell me the general reasons for the file breaking during file load

Comment: i guess there are such text fields which containing 'line break' or multiple 'line break' what you need to take out. In other case the loader/DB wont break the rows

Comment: it seems you dont used yet, np.
 So, open the file in notepad++ -> press Ctrl+H -> in the 'Find what' field type \n -> in the 'Replace with' take a space -> set the 'Search mode' to Extended -> hit Replace All

Comment: have you some error log? have you tried with a smaller set? what is the structure of the gtac7_rns table?

Comment: It is not displaying any error ,but it is breaking.

Comment: It is breaking down during  insertion , For that how we can find out?